# parse_str & sql_injection(mysql_real_escape_string)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have a question about parse_str and mysql_real_String.
Can I do like that and will effect all parameters from form?

```
 $post_data =  mysql_real_escape_string($_post['form']);
  parse_str($post_data,$query)
  print_r($query)
  INSERT INTO xyz(id,name) VALUES(1,$query['name'])
```

Or

```
parse_str($_POST['form'],$query)
INSERT INTO xyz(id,name) VALUES(1,$query['name'])
print_r($query)
```

So the question is if mysql_real_escape_String effect all POST params of $_post['form'] or I have to explicitly in SQL make that statement?.

Comment: Better approach would be to use prepared statements all together ...

Comment: Assuming you meant `$_POST` instead of `$_post`, why would you be submitting form values with url encoded data?

Comment: Please stop trying to come up with clever new ways of escaping data, that's exactly how security vulnerabilities are made. Escaping each individual string is tedious and boring, but it's the correct way to go. (...as a distant second choice after using prepared statements obviously.)

Answer (score 2):

[`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) and [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) work with different encodings. `parse_str` decodes the percent-encoding, which is not recognized by `mysql_real_escape_string`:

```
$_post['form'] = 'name='.rawurlencode('\'"\\');
$post_data =  mysql_real_escape_string($_post['form']);
parse_str($post_data, $query);
echo $query['name'];  // output: '"\
```

You need to apply the encodings in the right order. `mysql_real_escape_string` must always come just right before putting the value into the MySQL string literal.

As always, passing the values as parameters as provided by prepared statements would be the better solution.

Comment: I apreciate your answer. Thank you.